# How can I sort a list/matrix in a function?

Tags: ti-basic, ti-nspire

When I try to use `SortA` and `SortD` in a function:

```
Define test()=
Func
© Convoluted way of returning [0 1 2 4 5; 4 1 3 5 2]
Local a,b
a:=[1 5 2 0 4]
b:=[1 2 3 4 5]
SortA a,b
Return colAugment(a,b)
EndFunc
```

I get the error `Invalid in a function or current expression`. I think this is because `SortA` modifies variables and this isn't allowed in a function, only in a program. Is there a way to sort a list or matrix in this way in a function?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is declare b as a local variable (as well as a):

```
Local a,b
```

And then it shouldn't return the error you mentioned.

I hope that helped!

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work and I still get the same error. I believe the error is relating to the use of `SortA`.

Answer (score 0):

The function SortA, SortD appears to work fine on the App calculator, and as a Program, but not with in a function.

Check this and correct a few mistakes
Regards

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhPdJ.png)
[Running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4ZWN.png)

Comment: I am aware that `SortA` and `SortD` work in a program, but I was wondering how to sort a list or matrix in a *function*.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn’t sort matrices, I made this function that sorts a list in ascending order. I don’t think it’s very efficient though as it just loops through the list and calls `min`, but my use case was only for small lists up to around 5 elements and I wanted it to be quick to type on my handheld calculator.

```
© Can't name it sorta due to the builtin
Define srta(xs)=
Func
Local ys,x,i,j,k,l0,l
l0:=dim(xs)
ys:={}
For i,l,l0
  x:=min(xs)
  ys:=augment(ys,{x})
  l:=dim(xs)
  For j,1,l
    If xs[j]=x Then
      © This splices the element at j (x) out of the list xs
      xs:=seq(xs[k+piecewise(0,k<j,1)],k,1,l-1)
      Exit
    EndIf
  EndFor
EndFor
Return ys
EndFunc
```

To sort it in descending order, replace `min` with `max`.